# ClearType keeps turning off on Windows over RDP

Tags: windows-7, windows-10, windows-8, remote-desktop, cleartype

Every time I log onto the computer, ClearType is turned off. I can turn it on manually, but after the session ends, everything is back to ugly. Especially the Consolas font in Eclipse looks very bad. How do I force ClearType to stay enabled?

Comment: Question for visitors: Is this applicable to other Windows versions? If so, please leave a comment or edit the question.

Comment: Yes, I have this on 8.1 right now.

Answer (score 59, accepted):

Solution found. In the Windows remote desktop client, there is an option to enable all sorts of eye candy. In the Remote Desktop Connection dialog, click Show Options, navigate to the Experience tab and select a non-automatic connection speed. Then you can allow the desired visual options.

Comment: Niceeeeeeeeeeee

Comment: When using terminal mode `rdesktop` on Linux, you can use `-x 0x80` to enable this.

Comment: When using `xfreerdp` on Linux, you can use `+fonts` option to enable font smoothing.

Answer (score 1):

`ClearType` equivalent option in remote desktop client is `font smoothing`. After enabling that `ClearType` setting will always be on in the remote machine.